# How to pass parameters in kendo web method data source in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, kendo-ui

I have an asp.net application. I am using kendo bullet charts. It is developed in .net framework 2.0 so wcf service is not working. That is why I am using web methods for binding of remote data.

I want to pass value of a c# variable in kendo web method data source url but it is not working.

Here is my code,

```
var month = "<%= month %>";

dataSource: {
  type: "json",
  transport: {
    read: {
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/FetchCounts",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      datatype: "json"
    }
  },
  serverFiltering: false,
  serverSorting: false,
  schema: {
    //data: "d",
    data: month,
    model: {
      fields: {
        current: { type: "string" },
        target: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

which is not working.

I do not know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the data parameter in the wrong location of the Kendo UI DataSource definition. [Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data). This is how it should be set up:

```
dataSource: {
  type: 'json',
  transport: {
    read: {
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Default.aspx/FetchCounts',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: function () {
        return { 
          month: month 
        };
      }
    }
  },
  serverFiltering: false,
  serverSorting: false,
  schema: {
    //...
  }
}
```